# javascript frameworks and Java EE

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, javascript-framework

I am seeing a lot of nice client side frameworks emerging to build web GUIs (most recently http://yeoman.io/).  How should we leverage these frameworks when the server side is all Java EE?  None of them provide any detailed information on this.  I would appreciate it if you shared how you are leveraging these frameworks.

Comment: Why are people suggesting this to be closed. This is a valid question without ambiguity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach my team has taken is to treat front and back ends as almost separate applications,  communicating through REST. This approach allowed us to reuse the server and connect with two different clients which initially were not in the picture.

We use Dojo in the client side and an in-house Java framework for the backend.

I know I am not provided any detailed information as you requested, but I guess my recommendation is to not worry to much about it. Decouple client and server to produce a better solution.

Comment: I've seen this approach too, it allows using multiple clients that consume JSON or XML data produces by the backend. Then if one day you want to have for example a mobile app, you just have to write another client which consume the JSON data.

Comment: Agreed, don't use any server side rendering, let the client do all the rendering using these frameworks, and use your server only to retrieve and persist the data.  Makes it really easy to modify your domain model in the future, or change up your client app.